Conditional Formatting for Date and Time that is nearing the deadline
First off, I am really really ignorant on most of these other than basic formulas. I am the type to Google my logical request and copy and paste the formula to my cell, tweak a little bit to arrive to my purpose and that's it. So, really just a newbie on this. And with that, here's my question.
Basically, I just want to color the text or maybe highlight the cell of my deadline column (E - Client Due Date), that is near the deadline.My Cell Image
So let's say, for deadlines that are less than 8 hours will be in red, deadlines that are 8-16 hours will be in yellow, and deadlines with 16 hours or more will be in green. That's it.
Really hoping for your help on this one. Thanks!
Tried basic conditional formatting, but inexperience really just limits my capabilities.

First, note that you'd better format as a table.
You could use such formulas for conditional formatting (respect the color order here below when setting up the rules):


Formula 1 (red): =$E2 < NOW() + 8/24
Formula 2 (yellow): =$E2 < NOW() + 16/24
Formula 1 (green): =$E2 >= NOW() + 16/24

Note that NOW() provides date and time with the second as the resolution. Adjust if needed (I think it does not matter in your case).
Note that NOW() is a volatile function (it refreshes each time you modify the content of a cell): Microsoft documentation for NOW().
I guess that your criteria are not sufficient (missing what you want to do when in the past and/or depending on some action status (what if the action has already been performed?)).
